# Android - onGesture method not getting called in AccessibilityService

Tags: android, android-service, accessibilityservice

This is my meta-data resource for the accessibility resource:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
/>
```

My accessibility service class code

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Log.d("caller","service connected");
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    Log.d("caller","onAccessibilityEvent Called");
}
@Override
protected boolean onGesture(int gestureId) {
    Log.d("caller","on guesture called");
    return super.onGesture(gestureId);
}
```

I have tried setting accessebilityFlags to flagRequestFingerprintGestures still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Gesture events are only sent in touch exploration mode. I see that you have enabled this feature in your xml, but I don't see the code where you actually request that it get turned on.

This is a flag that you need to add to your xml

```
android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRequestTouchExplorationMode"
```

Comment: OK, but the click events are not triggered to the android. This code make touchscreen blocked. How to let the events and gestures pass and capture

Comment: How to get touch events by transparent layer and let them propagate to views below.(not consume events)

Comment: onGesture consume events, that is the issue. how to make it not consume

Comment: That's a different question! Ask it and link it.

Comment: @Duna learn some basic of OOP all I can, look at onGesture mathod return type  carefully return super.onGesture(gestureId);

Comment: @Hamza I am wondering what is the link between OOP and system call onGesture. Did you read the title of the issue? Your answer is not helping anyone

Comment: xD I comment on the post who told you I give the Answer?